# Undefined object from Angular HttpGet request from .net core IAction Result

Tags: angular, .net-core, http-get

I want to get the Message from the IActionResult of a HTTPGET Request, I haven't managed to get it working.  The response comes back, but I can't map it properly in Angular 12.

Angular Http Service:

```js
      finishCycle(): Observable<any> {
        return from(
          this.authService.getAccessToken()
          .then(token => {
            const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
            this.http.get(this.createCompleteRoute("api/Cycle/FinishCycle", this.envUrl.urlAddress),
              { headers: headers, withCredentials: true }).toPromise();
          }));
      }
```

Angular Component Method:

```js
      finishCycle() {
        this.spinner.show();
    
        var success;
    
        this.service.finishCycle().subscribe(res => {
          success = res;
          console.log(success);
          this.disableStart = false;
          this.spinner.hide();
        });
      }
```

C# Controller

```cs
       [HttpGet("/api/Cycle/FinishCycle")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FinishCycle()
        {
            this._finishCycle = new Thread(() => { this._waterCycleService.FinishCycle(); });
    
            this._finishCycle.Start();
    
            return this.Ok(new { Message = "Finished" });
        }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to lock the screen with a spinner until my process finishes, then on confirmation, enable the screen again.  It's not fully hooked up yet, but I do already know that the spinners, authentication etc.. all work, it's just my mapping that is off.

Comment: What do you see in the console after: `console.log(success);`?

Comment: Did you miss `return` statement before `this.http.get(...)`?

Comment: Indeed, missing a return.  Cheers